# Does Location.getSpeed() work?

Tags: android, android-location

I've seen alot of question stating that getSpeed() returns 0.0 but does it actually work? Or does hasSpeed() always return false or is it just for certain phones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does work with at least with GPS and on those devices I used up to now (mostly HTC and Samsung).

You will not get a speed in the emulator if you are providing single locations. Even when I  provided NMEA data streams to the emulator the speed was 0.0. But it works fine on the real device.

Comment: Thanks.Tried it out again there on the emulator and is giving back figures as well, probably not correct though.